# How to conditionally format within an autocompleting drop down?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, autocomplete

I am trying to build a web-based medical record system in MySQL and PHP. I have a table with all the available drugs, and a table which will hold any drug allergies each patient may have. I dynamically build an array of all available drugs and use that as the source of the Jquery autocomplete function for new drug prescriptions. That all works fine.

What I want to do is have each entry in the autocomplete suggestions drop down list formatted conditional on whether that particular patient is allergic to that drug - affected drugs may be greyed out, or in red for instance.

It is relatively easy to do this in a normal drop down box, but there are too many possible entries in the drug table for this to be an effective way to enter the data. It would be relatively easy to build the source list of drugs WITHOUT the  drugs that that patient is allergic to, but that doesn't appeal (for instance there may be situations where you will prescribe a drug and tolerate a mild adverse reaction).

Can anyone point me in the right direction to do this? I haven't included any code listings because it is all fairly generic to this point. I apologise if my question seems too vague. I have never asked a question here before, but have had a huge amount of help from the answers on the site.

Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid StackOverflow isn't really the place to ask questions as broad as this. It's more for specific code related questions :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you add an attribute to the items in the dropdown list to denote whether or they are allergic to each medication, and then use CSS to conditionally format based on the presence of this attribute?

Comment: That is how I can do it in a conventional drop down list, but when autocomplete is building the list on the fly, I can't see how to make it carry the second piece of data (allergy status)

Comment: You're using AJAX to get the search AutoComplete results, right? If so, have the AJAX add the attribute as well... Alternatively, bring down a list of medication to which the Patient is allergic once, and then write javascript code to run on the keypress, after the autocomplete keypress runs, to add the attribute as necessary...

Comment: Thanks Martin - exactly the prod I needed to get me thinking along the right lines. When the PHP dynamically builds the array, I can pass an allergy attribute. Then tweaked the javascript to conditionally format on that. Works like a charm!